# Removing text after second occurence of specific character in a string - any better way to do it?

Tags: python-3.x, string, slice

On this example I'd like to remove text after second comma.
string = "This is string, remove text after second comma, to be removed."

I've came up with this solution:

```
text = "This is string, remove text after second comma, to be removed."

k=  (text.find(",")) #find "," in a string
m = (text.find(",", k+1)) #Find second "," in a string
new_string = text[:m]

print(new_string)
```

It works but how to make it in more Pythonic way?

Comment: One possibility is ','.join(s.split(',')[:2]), with s = "This is string, remove text after second comma, to be removed.".

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
 text = "This is string, remove text after second comma, to be removed."
 print(''.join(text[:[pos for pos, char in enumerate(text) if char == ','][1]+1]))
```